# How to run a rake task depending on environment?

Tags: ruby, rake, mixpanel

I'm trying to export Mixpanel raw data, as documented here
https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/exporting-raw-data-you-inserted-into-mixpanel

As the Mixpanel team didn't bother to just provide a script doing this, a kind soul made this Rake task
https://gist.github.com/wongpeiyi/3217208

I figured out that it needs to go into a file named "Rakefile", and executed with

```
$ rake mixpanel:pull
```

However, that gives

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'environment'

Tasks: TOP => mixpanel:pull
```

How can this task be run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rake task was problably written to be included in a rails project. You can just remove the dependency on the `:environment` task.

So change the `task` line to

```
task :pull do
```

that should do the trick. It could be possible that some gems are missing (that is what the `:environment` task does: it loads the rails environment).